# Understand Error build DELPHI app with JENKINS

Tags: delphi, jenkins

I try to use Jenkins as a build tool for my DELPHI apps.  I followed the instructions as given here  [tutorial DELPHI with JENKINS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dhKGmp6KsNs) , some of my apps failed with the following consolde output.

here is the Batch file content

```
call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\19.0\bin\rsvars.bat"
echo PATH TO PROJECT 
cd %1
echo  PROJECTNAME 
msbuild %2
```

the Build action  is defined as following

```
%JENKINS_HOME%\jobs\build.bat "%WORKSPACE%\test"   ProjectFile.dproj
```

How to understand and fix this error, as the app is compiling within DELPHI IDE without any issue.  The path mentioned in the error msg does not exist on my computer

```
Build started 15.04.2018 21:58:59.
Project "C:\.....\Tool.dproj" on node 0 (default targets).
C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\19.0\bin\CodeGear.Common.Targets : warning : Expected configuration file missing - C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\Embarcadero\BDS\19.0\EnvOptions.proj
_PasCoreCompile:
  Embarcadero Delphi for Win32 compiler version 32.0
  Copyright (c) 1983,2017 Embarcadero Technologies, Inc.
C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\19.0\Bin\CodeGear.Delphi.Targets(399,5): error E1026: File not found: 'Controls.res'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\19.0\Bin\CodeGear.Delphi.Targets(399,5): error E1026: File not found: 'Tabs.res'
Done Building Project "C:\....\Tool.dproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.

Build FAILED.
```

Comment: What does your Jenkins job do?  Specifically, what's the command that generates the error you posted?

Comment: Maybe you just need to supply a path to the .res files it can't find right now?

Comment: You need fix first warninig

Comment: add  info on our jenkins scripts

Comment: Does it work if you call your batch file manually?    Is your Jenkins server running as the system user or as a local/domain Windows user?  Does the Jenkins job work if you change it to run as your user?

Answer (score 1):

I have an error similar to this with different .RES and .DCU Delphi files. 
In Windows 7 and greatest versions is necessary change the account configured in Jenkings Service.

Go to the **"Services management"** and select the Jenkins service. Open the **properties** and select the **"Log On"** tab.
Select **"This account"** (used to install Delphi) and fill the values.

[image]

Try to recompile the project.

Comment: could not find this service management topic, checked JENKINS settings via explorer, and services in TASK manager

Comment: in Start button search the run option and type "services.msc" to access the Service Management. Another alternative is user [WINDOWSKEY]+[R] and type "services.msc".

Comment: found mentioned menue now - all items had been disabled, but up to now failed to add my account even running services.msc in admin mode